# Can't get dropdown checkbox to display with keyboard only input using aria

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm new to aria and this one partially works.  I can tab to the field but can't see the individual items in the dropdown.  Any suggestions appreciated.

```
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="0">
    <span id="anchor" class="anchor" aria-haspopup="true">Select Color</span>
    <ul id="items" class="items" aria-label="submenu">
    <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"/><label>red </label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"/><label>blue </label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"/><label>yellow</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"/><label>green </label></li>
</ul>                       
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? checkboxes display https://jsfiddle.net/Ld6b4epv/1/

Comment: The question is how to display when I tab into field.  The field starts closed and I would like it to  open on focus (for accessibility)

Comment: I just got it working and wanted to share answer in JS $("#list1").focus and set the display to block

Answer (score 2):

> I just got it working and wanted to share answer in JS `$("#list1").focus` and set the display to block

Your labels do not have any `for` attribute and do not enclose the `input` checkboxes.

You should remove the `role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"` attributes which are redundant and you have to give a `name` attribute.

The `span` element does not have a `tabindex` you have to use a `button` element (or add a `tabindex=0` attribute in order for the span to be focusable and give it an appropriate `role`).

The `ul` has an aria label "submenu" which does not appear to describe correctly the content of the list.

You should remove the `tabindex` from the outer `div` as it encloses other focusable elements.

Valid code:

```
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
    <button id="anchor" class="anchor" aria-haspopup="true">Select Color</button>
    <ul id="items" class="items">
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="red" />red </label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="blue" />blue </label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="yellow" />yellow</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="green" />green </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```